# Download as zip from Minio

Tags: java, minio

I'm trying to create a zip file from the object path I'm passing to minio. In minio objects are stored as paths, i.e. `my/path/to/file.jpg`.

```
private void zip(HttpServletResponse response, String bucket, String path) {
  try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream()) {
    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path));
    StreamUtils.copy(getObjectFromMinio(bucket, path), zos);
    zos.closeEntry();
  } catch (Exception e) { ... }
}
```

`getObjectFromMinio` uses standard `getObject` method.

Everything is fine until I'm trying to build nested folders by passing `my/path/` as path argument.

How to build the folder structure correctly inside the zip file with `InputStream`?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @k314159 no error, just the result zip has 1 kb.

Comment: The way you build the zip file using the folder path is correct. It must be something else. Have you debugged getObjectFromMinio? You're supposed to close the InputStream; where do you do that?